# Possible to restrict format/layout/fonts of Wikis & blogs?

Tags: blog, content, formatting, enterprise-wiki

Is there a way that I can restrict the text formatting(font etc)/layout on the Sharepoint blog/Wiki sites? Or doesSharepoint have any options to control the HTML that is being generated when users enter content(like copy paste from word)???

Thank you very much for reading, any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Enterprise Wiki:

- enable the Publishing Feature for the Site Collection
- Create a page layout based on the Enterprise Wiki Page
- In SPD, edit the properties of the tag PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField (turn on the Properties panel)
- There's a whole raft of properties that you can toggle from TRUE to FALSE to allow/disallow Fonts, styles, links, etc.
- Save and publish the page layout.
- Activate that page layout to the Enterprise Wiki site (via Site Settings > Page Layout and Site Template Settings) and remove the out-of-the-box Enterprise Wiki Page from the permitted page layouts

Depending on which properties were changed in the page layout, certain elements of the Formatting ribbon will be grayed out.

There's a great walk-through at Waldek Mastykarz's blog:
http://blog.mastykarz.nl/consistent-content-authoring-sharepoint-2010-rich-text-editor/

Microsoft has an overview of what each property does here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.richhtmlfield_properties.aspx

Comment: finally I came across this. Very helpful. Thanks @teylyn

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you might be looking for but its related.

If you are looking for a way to include new custom fonts, then below is the way

[MS Forum post here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Developer/Issue-adding-custom-fonts-in-to-font-picker-in-ribbon-SharePoint/m-p/45043/highlight/false#M1468)

**For custom fonts:**

1. Import the fonts file in your CSS first

> @import url(/sites/sitecollection/SiteAssets/Gotham_fonts.css) all;

2. Then include the below in your CSS

> .ms-rteFontFace-GothamNarrow{
>       -ms-name:"Gotham Narrow";
>       font-family: "GothamNarrowBook", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important; }

**Additional**:
If you need custom styles, then use below:

> .ms-rteStyle-CustomChevronHeadingStyleDSmall{
>       -ms-name:"Chevron Heading Dark - small";
>       color: #0c2d71;
>       font-size:15px;
>       font-weight:bold; }